# How can I remove my user name from a friends Google login page?

Tags: gmail, login

I checked my Gmail on a friend work computer, whose company also has a work Gmail account. Now when either of us login to email, part of the other person's name appears. This is frustrating for me since my Google photos are linked to Gmail. Doubly frustrating for him because it's a work computer. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- log out
- open **https://accounts.google.com/**
- select **Remove account**
- click on that **X**
- select **Yes, remove**
- done

[image: x]